# Creating a table with DECIMAL(11,8) but it's getting DECIMAL(11,0)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a table and inside the table, there are two fields latitude and longitude with variable decimal(10,8) and (11,8) but it's taking only (10,0) and (11,0).I am using PHPMyAdmin 4.6.4 version. Please help me in this.

1)[image]
2) [image]
3)
[image]

Comment: if you are using lat,lng use spatial data types

Comment: This is just bug in PhpMyAdmin. I am alos waiting for the next version

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the first digit of the `DECIMAL` declaration is the total digits.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Dennys, I can't get you. Can you explain me little more with an example? Please